# Ensure query executes even if connection to Postgres database is lost

Tags: postgresql

I'll often create a ssh tunnel to a remote database and query the database with a local client.

Sometimes, I have to make a very long-running command, typically to create a table.

Is there anything I can do to ensure that a query will not be cancelled if the client loses the connection to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command on the server in a `tmux` session on that server. If you are disconnected `tmux` will maintain your terminal, processes will continue to run, and you can reconnect to it whenever your network connectivity is restored.